# TestNg IAnnotationTransformer listener on the class level

Tags: testng, testng.xml

I have this requirement to have an IAnnotationTransformer for manipulating the @Test annotation during runtime. Also i want to define this annotation on the class level instead of the TestNG XML.

```
@Listeners(MyAnnotationTransformer.class)
public class TestClass {
   ...
}
```

MyAnnotationTransformer.java:

```
public class MyAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

        System.out.println("Gotcha!!");
    }
}
```

The problem is the MyAnnotationTransformer's transform method is not called during execution.

However, if I provide the MyAnnotationTransformer Listener at the XML level, this is successful.

```
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.debugger89.testng.MyAnnotationTransformer" />
</listeners>
```

The official documentation does not mention any restriction like this. Is this a bug?
Using TestNG version 7.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at javadoc:

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/annotations/Listeners.html

> Any class that implements the interface ITestNGListener is allowed, **except IAnnotationTransformer which need to be defined in XML** since they have to be known before we even start looking for annotations.

`IAnnotationTransformer` can be defined

- in XML
- via command line: `java org.testng.TestNG -listener MyAnnotationTransformer testng.xml`
- programmatically

  ```
  TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
  testNg.addListener(new MyAnnotationTransformer());
  ```

---

See also https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/446